# Соединения с сайтом робота Яндекса, NGINX Centos7

Tags: linux, nginx, битрикс, centos

Есть сайт на битрикс, NGINX + Centos7.
Робот яндекса не может достучаться до сайта, нет соединения. В access.log и error.log по этому поводу ничего. Fail2ban на всякий случай пробовал отключать - безрезультатно. Где еще можно посмотреть причину?

Comment: Боты других поисковиков, судя по access.log, соединяются успешно.

Comment: А robots.txt в корне случайно нет? Может там прописан запрет для Яндекс бота.

Comment: Не может достучаться или не стучится?